# AndroidRuntimeException while trying to start activity in custom ListView Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-activity

I'm getting am AndroidRuntimeException when I click the menuButton using this custom ListView Adapter:

```
public class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Menu>{

    private List<Menu> menus;

    public MenuAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Menu> menus){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, menus);
        this.menus = menus;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View menuView = convertView;
        if (menuView == null){
            LayoutInflater menuViewInflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            menuView = menuViewInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_row, null);
        }

        Menu menu = menus.get(position);
        if (menu != null) {
            Button menuButton = (Button)menuView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
            menuButton.setText(menu.name);
            menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent menuIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MenuActivity.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(menuIntent);
                }
            });
        }
        return menuView;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the full LogCat output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your trying to do with v.getContext(),. Try something like below

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent);
```

or

```
startActivity(new Intent("Your.Package.name.classnameinManifest"));
```